# excel vba sum of grouped values, divide and add to the table final

Tags: excel, vba

i am looking for to a solution in VBA to sum and group values from a table

my table is similar to this:

```
Tagname Aggregate   Timestamp   Value
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 5:59 129115
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 6:00 128955
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 6:01 132840
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 6:02 134610
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 6:03 127465
CHZHA   Raw 13/06/2021 6:04 131380
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 5:59 57625
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:00 54830
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:01 57040
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:02 55715
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:03 57200
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:04 54600
CHZHB   Raw 13/06/2021 6:05 81230
```

i need to add last rows like this:

```
CHZHA   TOTAL   13/06/2021 0:00 544,69
CHZHB   TOTAL   13/06/2021 0:00 252,36
```

the values are the sum of all values grouped by each tag and divided 1440(minutes in a day)
don't need to calculate timestamp, all the data is in the same day

i cannot use pivot table because i need to automate it for each day, before exporting to csv

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a Pivot Table! No VBA needed.

Pivot Tables can group things up based on values in the source table and display the groups data. You can add a formula value where you take the sum of one column and divide it by 1440.

[image: pivottableexample]

This pivottable will automatically update as the source table is updated. You will want to move the pivot table to the side or onto a new sheet to make room for new data.

To make that calculated field for the pivot table, Click on the Pivot Table, go to the Options Tab in the ribbon, -> Formulas -> Calculated Field.
The formula is `=Value /1440`. When you put that new calculated field into the Values section of the pivot table, it defaults to summing all the data in the field, which is what you wanted.

Comment: Side Note: To get your table to look like mine, go to the Design tab in the Ribbon. Subtotals: Do Not Show Subtotals. Grand Totals: Off for Rows and Columns. Report Layout: Show in Tabular Form.

Comment: yes, but i need to do in VBA, because i am doing an automated script and data refresh each day.